# How to automatically import xlsx-file in mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel

is there any way that I can upload an xlsx-file to my mysql database automatically every 12 hours?

I have an xlsx-file with around 600 rows. The target table already exists. 
I would like to perform the following steps:
1. Delete the content of the existing table.
2. Insert the data from the xlsx-file.

This should be performed every 12 hours. Is there a way doing this without using php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link may be useful:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) provided that the file is in `CSV` foremat else convert the file to CSV format.

> 1. Delete the content of the existing table.

Before you do so take a backup of the table. You can create a backup intermediary table and insert the data there.

> 2. Insert the data from the xlsx-file.

use `LOAD DATA INFILE` and import the data.

> This should be performed every 12 hours.

You can create a SQL script with all this steps. Create a scheduled task (Windows) which runs every 12 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Data Import tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (command-line mode).

How to:

- Create data-import template file: open Data Import master, select target table, check Repopulate mode (delete all + inserts), and save template file.
- Use created template to import your file in command-line mode. Use Windows Scheduled Tasks to run it periodically.